# All Linux installations fail on my laptop

Tags: linux, boot, installation

I just bought an Acer Aspire S3, Intel i5 and Intel HD 4000. At first there was Windows 7 and I deleted it, then installed Ubuntu 12.10. Everything went OK and then I updated it to 13.04. Then the graphics card didn't seem to work. I uninstalled it and there was no OS on my laptop.

I don't know why, but after that I couldn't install almost any kind of Linux distribution. I've tried Ubuntu, Fedora, Mint and Arch. I think others as well.

They're all the same. I boot from USB (there is no CD-ROM), and I can see the install image. After I press *Install*, they all turn to a black screen. And then the CPU stops working.

How can I install Linux now?

Comment: Not all Linux distros fail.  You told us that Ubuntu 12.10 worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to try:

- reset the BIOS. Tweak any BIOS settings which might affect this, especially the ones related to the graphics card. Try "fail-safe defaults" (or similar) in your BIOS.
- try to install in "safe mode" if available by using a "generic" graphic driver. Dunno if this option is available for your OS/graphic card. Be careful, sometimes the driver chosen 'automatically' by the installer isn't the best one. Sometimes is better to install the bare-bone driver and after that upgrade it by hand with the latest one from the manufacturer and not from the distro.
- try to put Windows on it again. Any Windows: XP, the original Win7 etc. It works? If yes, try to put the latest Windows HD 4000 driver for your OS. It (still) works? If not, then perhaps you have a problem with your on-die VGA and you must return your notebook.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Acer Aspire S3 I believe has UEFI you need to turn off secure boot.

This explains, what is UEFI? 
http://www.pcpro.co.uk/features/381565/uefi-bios-explained

This link will help you.
http://www.zdnet.com/my-experiments-with-multi-boot-selection-with-uefi-boot-manager-7000013627/

Before I get flamed, there are many types of Linux from Arch to Zorin. Ubuntu is popular but choose one that you like.